# Need to trim new lines from MySql result

Tags: mysql, magento, csv, newline, trim

I am backing up data from a Magento database using MySql workbench. Here is the query I'm using:

```
Select FName.value AS 'FirstName' ,
LName.value AS 'LastName' ,
e.email,
Address1.value AS Address1, 
City.value AS City ,
Province.value as Province ,
Country.value AS 'CountryCode' ,
Zip.value AS Zip ,
Phone.value AS Phone
FROM customer_entity e 
JOIN customer_address_entity ae ON ae.parent_id = e.entity_id 
JOIN customer_entity_int cei ON e.entity_id = cei.entity_id and cei.attribute_id=13 and cei.value=ae.entity_id 
left JOIN customer_address_entity_varchar FName ON ae.entity_id = FName.entity_id        and FName.attribute_id = (select attribute_id from eav_attribute where entity_type_id=2 and attribute_code='firstname')
left JOIN customer_address_entity_varchar LName ON ae.entity_id = LName.entity_id         and LName.attribute_id= (select attribute_id from eav_attribute where entity_type_id=2 and attribute_code='lastname')
left JOIN customer_address_entity_varchar Zip ON ae.entity_id = Zip.entity_id                         and Zip.attribute_id = (select attribute_id from eav_attribute where entity_type_id=2 and attribute_code='postcode')
left JOIN customer_address_entity_varchar City ON ae.entity_id = City.entity_id                      and City.attribute_id= (select attribute_id from eav_attribute where entity_type_id=2 and attribute_code='city')
left JOIN customer_address_entity_varchar Phone ON ae.entity_id = Phone.entity_id           and Phone.attribute_id = (select attribute_id from eav_attribute where entity_type_id=2 and attribute_code='telephone') 
left JOIN customer_address_entity_varchar Province ON ae.entity_id = Province.entity_id and Province.attribute_id = (select attribute_id from eav_attribute where entity_type_id=2 and attribute_code='region')
left JOIN customer_address_entity_varchar Country ON ae.entity_id = Country.entity_id    and Country.attribute_id = (select attribute_id from eav_attribute where entity_type_id=2 and attribute_code='country_id')
left JOIN customer_address_entity_text Address1 ON ae.entity_id = Address1.entity_id     and Address1.attribute_id = (select attribute_id from eav_attribute where entity_type_id=2 and attribute_code='street')
```

All I really need to do is strip new lines out of the Address1 field because it's breaking a CSV parser that I use.  I tried:

```
TRIM(\n FROM Address1.value) as Address1
```

on the fourth line of the query, but that was unsuccessful.  My knowledge of MySql is obviously limited and any help will save me a number of hours deleting new lines.

Answer (score 1):

You could remove all "\n" from the `Address1.value` field by running

```sql
UPDATE customer_address_entity_text SET value=REPLACE(value,'\n','')
```

and afterwards running your query.

Another solution would be to use `REPLACE()` in your `SELECT` statement:

```sql
REPLACE(Address1.value, '\n', '') as Address1
```

which results in

```sql
Select FName.value AS 'FirstName' ,
LName.value AS 'LastName' ,
e.email,
REPLACE(Address1.value, '\n', '') AS Address1, 
City.value AS City ,
Province.value as Province ,
Country.value AS 'CountryCode' ,
Zip.value AS Zip ,
Phone.value AS Phone
FROM customer_entity e 
JOIN customer_address_entity ae ON ae.parent_id = e.entity_id 
JOIN customer_entity_int cei ON e.entity_id = cei.entity_id and cei.attribute_id=13 and cei.value=ae.entity_id 
left JOIN customer_address_entity_varchar FName ON ae.entity_id = FName.entity_id        and FName.attribute_id = (select attribute_id from eav_attribute where entity_type_id=2 and attribute_code='firstname')
left JOIN customer_address_entity_varchar LName ON ae.entity_id = LName.entity_id         and LName.attribute_id= (select attribute_id from eav_attribute where entity_type_id=2 and attribute_code='lastname')
left JOIN customer_address_entity_varchar Zip ON ae.entity_id = Zip.entity_id                         and Zip.attribute_id = (select attribute_id from eav_attribute where entity_type_id=2 and attribute_code='postcode')
left JOIN customer_address_entity_varchar City ON ae.entity_id = City.entity_id                      and City.attribute_id= (select attribute_id from eav_attribute where entity_type_id=2 and attribute_code='city')
left JOIN customer_address_entity_varchar Phone ON ae.entity_id = Phone.entity_id           and Phone.attribute_id = (select attribute_id from eav_attribute where entity_type_id=2 and attribute_code='telephone') 
left JOIN customer_address_entity_varchar Province ON ae.entity_id = Province.entity_id and Province.attribute_id = (select attribute_id from eav_attribute where entity_type_id=2 and attribute_code='region')
left JOIN customer_address_entity_varchar Country ON ae.entity_id = Country.entity_id    and Country.attribute_id = (select attribute_id from eav_attribute where entity_type_id=2 and attribute_code='country_id')
left JOIN customer_address_entity_text Address1 ON ae.entity_id = Address1.entity_id     and Address1.attribute_id = (select attribute_id from eav_attribute where entity_type_id=2 and attribute_code='street')
```

Answer (score 0):

Go at that with a different route.

Get rid of the trim and stuff

```
TRIM(\n FROM Address1.value) as Address1
```

Would be

```
table.address1 as Address1
```

Then after all your joins add a WHERE clause and set that to a date of which you would consider new.

Would be something like:

```
WHERE date =< 2016-04-28
```

That should make it so that it will only show rows with that date column older than todays date.

Oh and also if you dont actually wanna use a date column but you know what ID # the new lines begin on you can always use that as well. It should be the same syntax but with different columns

Hope that helps. If you need more help just lemme know

Another thing to note is its recommended to have table and column names in lower case. So i would do some editing on these as well and make sure everything is lower case since SQL recognizes the Capitalization

Comment: I need all of them, so I don't want to limit by date with a WHERE clause.  What I need is a way to make sure the Address1.value does not have any newline characters in it (\n).

Comment: How about trying: Where address1.value NOT LIKE '/n'

that should collect the substring /n and not allow it. is that more of what you're looking for?